# how to use onActivityResult( ) in fragment

Tags: android

this code must return cropped image in `imageView` in `fragment` 
i am using cropper image to crop image and then put it in `imageView` its work in `activity` bit not work in fragment

```
Package com.example.rami_.esmatsongs;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {
    private ImageView profile_picture;
    private TextView edit_profile_picture;
    public AccountFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
        profile_picture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        profile_picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cropImage();
            }
        });
        edit_profile_picture = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.changeProfilePic);
        edit_profile_picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cropImage();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void cropImage() {
        CropImage.activity()
                 .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                 .setMinCropResultSize(512, 512)
                 .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                 .getIntent(getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri postImageUri = result.getUri();
                profile_picture.setImageURI(postImageUri);
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

mainActivity code

```
package com.example.rami_.esmatsongs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView mainbottomNav;
    private HomeFragment homeFragment;
    private NotificationFragment notificationFragment;
    private AccountFragment accountFragment;
    private AboutFragment aboutFragment;
    private Uri mCropImageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // FRAGMENTS
        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        notificationFragment = new NotificationFragment();
        accountFragment = new AccountFragment();
        aboutFragment = new AboutFragment();
        initializeFragment();
        mainbottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.mainBottomNav);
        mainbottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.home_bottom:
                        replaceFragment(homeFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.account_bottom:
                        replaceFragment(accountFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.notification_bottom:
                        replaceFragment(notificationFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.about_bottom:
                        replaceFragment(aboutFragment);
                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initializeFragment() {

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, homeFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, notificationFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, accountFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, aboutFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.hide(notificationFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.hide(accountFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.hide(aboutFragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }


    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (fragment == homeFragment) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(notificationFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(accountFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(aboutFragment);
        }

        if (fragment == accountFragment) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(homeFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(notificationFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(aboutFragment);
        }

        if (fragment == notificationFragment) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(homeFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(accountFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(aboutFragment);
        }

        if (fragment == aboutFragment) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(homeFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(accountFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(notificationFragment);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
        //fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: it is also work in fragment :)

Comment: what problem arise if it is not working ? specified it

Comment: try `CropImage.activity()
                 .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                 .setMinCropResultSize(512, 512)
                 .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                 .getIntent(getActivity());`

Comment: .getIntent(getActivity());  also not working

Comment: kindly go through complete documentation before implementing any third party [see](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper#using-activity) 3rd point 3rd code snip

Comment: `.start(getContext(), this);`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 public void cropImage()
    {
        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setMinCropResultSize(512, 512)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .getIntent(getContext());
    }
```

to

```
 public void cropImage()
    {
        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setMinCropResultSize(512, 512)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(getContext(), this);
    }
```

So the results will be delivered to the fragment and not to the activity

From [Android Image Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper#using-activity) repository

You can start the CropImageActivity from the fragment and receive the result in the fragment onActivityResult method.
Using AppCompat fragment is the best option that allows you to use direct start method:

**UPDATE:**

Watch [this](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/661) issue in their Git Repository, suggesting another option,

you can get the intent and start the activity manually:

```
Intent intent = CropImage.activity(imageUri)
   .getIntent(getContext());
startActivityForResult(intent,CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: public void cropImage()
    {
        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setMinCropResultSize(512, 512)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(getContext(), this);
    } also not working iwill add main activity code to see all code

Comment: thanks man its work 
i have error in this line not found and   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 0):

Overide onActivityResult in Activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragmentById = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if (fragmentById != null) {
        fragmentById.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: i add this in main activity and app crush

Comment: use ur container id main_container